# How to get back to having OPEN IN SINGLE INSTANCE" as default for Excel 2007?

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-excel-2007

In June Mikhail asked the same question but the answer was how to do the opposite (make multiple instances the default).
I am trying to get to an answer to Mikhail's question which I rephrase as :-

I have same problem with 64 byte Windows 7 and Excel 2007. Excel always used to open in a single instance n o matter how/where I opened the sheets. Because of this I could always copy and paste, etc with full formatting, formulas, etc. Suddenly, Excel switched to opening everything in fresh, separate, multiple instances and destroyed the basic cut and paste options.

Wasn't the original question how to go back to everything in a single instance ? I have been searching for the answer to that question (rather than the opposite).

Comment: pnuts Yes unchecked but checking it does not make single instance the default (it only brings a new set of problems which are documented elsewhere). I am not totally certain but I strongly suspect that the single instance default went away with a recent Windows/Office update. I have also installed the Skype fix that some say causes my problem in Excel - no success.

Comment: pnuts   -   Yes I did find it before posting my question. It does say that it works with XP and Excel 2003 BUT, a clue when it comes to Win7 and Excel 2007 is the bit that says - "Check “Ignore other applications” for separate instances. That instruction is different and does not have the same results. IE not a solution. rwweks
Uncheck “Ignore other applications” for a single instance"

Comment: Somehow, what appeared was not what I typed. The main point being that not only is that specific instruction no longer available but checking the current one causes different problems and leaving it unchecked has no effect on the single instance requirement. This still stands at - "HOW TO GET RID OF MULTIPLE INSTANCES WITH EXCEL 2007 RUNNING ON WINDOWS 7 (both fully updated)  rweeks

Comment: Thanks pnuts even if your suggestions did not work. It seems no one knows the solution, which is strange since it was Microsoft Help from within Excel that sent me to this site. rweeks